# "WebGL - Up and Running" oddity: Should one use constructor instances as prototypes?

Tags: javascript, webgl, three.js

In the book "WebGL - Up and Running" a custom geometry is constructed, in a very undramatic way. However, the second to last line of code raised my eyebrows. The code is as follows:

```
Saturn.Rings = function ( innerRadius, outerRadius, nSegments ) {

    THREE.Geometry.call( this );

    var outerRadius = outerRadius || 1,

    ...snip snip snip...


    this.computeCentroids();
    this.computeFaceNormals();

    this.boundinSphere = { radius: outerRadius };
};

Saturn.Rings.prototype = new THREE.Geometry();
Saturn.Rings.prototype.constructor = Saturn.Rings;
```

My question is: why does he use a constructor instance in the prototype chain? Why can't `Saturn.Rings.prototype` just be a new blank object that inherits from `THREE.Geometry.prototype`? Shouldn't all stuff worth inheriting be positioned in `THREE.Geometry.prototype`? Why does he make the prototype an instance of the Geometry-constructor? (I am aware that the prototype chain is still correct, as the new prototype gets to inherit from `THREE.Geometry`'s prototype).

Also, in the second line in the code above, instances of `Saturn.Rings` are put through the `THREE.Geometry` constructor. Thus, they get all they could dream of from `THREE.Geometry` construction process. Thus, there is no need to do the same to their prototype.

Lets take a look at how a similar geometry is handled in three.js itself:

```
THREE.CubeGeometry = function ( width, height, depth, segmentsWidth, segmentsHeight, segmentsDepth, materials, sides ) {

    THREE.Geometry.call( this );

    ...snip snip snip...


    }

    this.computeCentroids();
    this.mergeVertices();

};

THREE.CubeGeometry.prototype = Object.create( THREE.Geometry.prototype );
```

Way neater. The only problem is that he forgets to set the prototype's 'constructor'-property to point back to `THREE.CubeGeometry`, but that's another matter.

Comment: For a little history, see this [three.js issue](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/2080).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling the constructor is probably done for compatibility.  `Object.create()` is a relatively new addition to JavaScript and is unsupported by some browsers released  prior to the publication of ECMAScript 5 (such as IE8 and IE7).  Just calling the constructor of another object is not enough for the object to inherit the other object's prototype ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yTevE/)).  Certainly there are benefits to avoiding invoking the parent object's constructor, but whether `Object.create()` is "Way neater" is debatable.

Comment: Agree. The dog has to either have it's prototype generated by 'new Animal' or Object.Create

Comment: Do you agree that the prototype is exposed too a needles construction process by the constructor, when using the 'new <constructor>' approach?

Comment: @loldrup - Sure, but calling the constructor is necessary if you want to support browsers released before ECMAScript 5.  The other alternative would be to use a shim for `Object.create()`.

Comment: @gilly3 - wouldn't the `Object.create()` way cure any problems with calling constructors which want to validate parameters? Or is this considered bad style with JS anyway? Thanks -

Comment: @virtualnobi - If you want to inherit a prototype without calling a constructor, for whatever reason, `Object.create()` is fine.  I hesitate to say it will "cure" any problems... It seems likely that bypassing parameter validation could *cause* problems.  But, it all depends... it's impossible to speak generally about that.  I'm not sure what you're referring to when you say "Is this considered bad style".  Is *what* considered bad style?

Comment: @gilly - not clear, I guess: `Subclass.prototype = new Superclass ();` creates a superclass instance without params and if you validate params in the superclass constructor, it'll generate spurious errors due to missing or invalid params. I was asking whether `Object.create (Superclass.prototype);` is a good replacement. Thinking about it, I guess NO: `Superclass.prototype` is not an `instanceof Superclass`... right? | "Is this bad style" referred to validating parameters in constructors - I think it's required (especially in JS), but maybe there's a better place? Thanks -

Comment: @virtualnobi - [`Object.create(Superclass.prototype) instanceof Superclass` returns `true`](http://jsfiddle.net/AdpZP/).  It all boils down to *why* the constructor validates parameters.  If the object's methods rely on values processed by the constructor in order to function correctly, you'd better know what your doing before bypassing the constructor. Otherwise, it seems to me that the constructor ought to be more tolerant.  Generally speaking.